# Mongo aggregation to fetch indexed values from string

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is the sample document

```
{   
  "pId":12345,    
     "charges": {
         "key1": "10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0",
         "key2": "22.5%,12.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%,22.5%",
         "key3": "271.95,371.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,271.95,394.45,271.95,394.45",
         ...
    }
}
```

Charge keys are dynamic. I wanted to fetch the requested index values from charges

Ex: input index is (1, 2)
the expected result is.

```
{   
  "pId":12345,    
     "charges": {
         "key1": "11.0,12.0",
         "key2": "12.5%,22.5%",
         "key3": "371.95,271.95",
         ...
    }
}
```

I tried with this projection

Stage1:

> { "$project" : { "pId" : 1,  "charges" : { "key1" : { "$split" :
> ["$$charges.key1", ","]}}}},

Stage2:

> { "$project" : { "pId" : 1, "charges" :  "$concat" : [{
> "$arrayElemAt" : ["$$charges.key1", 1]}, ",", { "$arrayElemAt" :
> ["$$charges.key1", 2]}]}}}]}

For this projection, I need to know the key names and need to mention all keys in the projection. Is there any other way to dynamically split and get indexed values for all keys from the charges map?

Comment: Is this something that you are looking for? [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lA_bgiJk-Sj)

Comment: Yes. However, after the split, I wanted to contact the array values by using the input index.  ($concat). Thanks.

Comment: Apologize, I miss out to convert the array back to string, should be as: [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P94QpE8VEEd)

Comment: Thank you. It is working. What is the diff between $project and $set?

Comment: Both are for the projection field. `$project` is used which you want to define the final output document. `$set` is used to set a new field/overwrite the field if existed. When you use the `$set` stage, the other field that is not mentioned in this stage will still remain in the output document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDb playground link : https://mongoplayground.net/p/kToLhxCN93f

`$concat with $cond & $gt` used to add comma(,) in string if **$$value** is not empty.

`reduce:` traverses array (can apply some operations) and returns string instead of array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      pId: 1,
      "charges": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": "$charges"
          },
          in: {
            K: "$$this.k",
            v: {
              "$split": [
                "$$this.v",
                ","
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      pId: 1,
      charges: {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          $map: {
            input: "$charges",
            in: {
              k: "$$this.K",
              v: {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": {
                    "$map": {
                      //input array of index to fetch values
                      "input": [
                        0,
                        2
                      ],
                      "as": "index",
                      "in": {
                        "$arrayElemAt": [
                          "$$this.v",
                          "$$index"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "initialValue": "",
                  "in": {
                    "$concat": [
                      "$$value",
                      {
                        "$cond": [
                          {
                            "$gt": [
                              "$$value",
                              ""
                            ]
                          },
                          ",",
                          ""
                        ]
                      },
                      "$$this"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `$set` - Set the `charges` field by converting the key-value pair for the `charges` object into an array for easier iteration.
2. `$set` - Set the `charges` field.

   2.1. `$map` - Iterate each element of the `charges` array and replace the `v` field by splitting the string into an array.
3. `$set` - Set the `charges` field.

   3.1. `$map` - Iterate each element of the `charges` array and return a new array.

   3.1.1. `$trim` - Trim the input string to remove the (extra) front and extra comma character.

   3.1.1.1. `$reduce` - Iterate each element of the array and transform to return a string.

   3.1.1.1.1. `input` - With the `$map` operator to iterate each value of your array indexes and get the value by index via `$arrayElemAt`.

   3.1.1.1.2. `initialValue` - Empty string

   3.1.1.1.3. `in` - Combine the accumulated string value with the current iterate string value with "," via `$concat`.
4. `$set` - Set the `charges` field by converting the array into a key-value pair.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "charges": {
        $objectToArray: "$charges"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "charges": {
        $map: {
          input: "$charges",
          in: {
            k: "$$this.k",
            v: {
              $split: [
                "$$this.v",
                ","
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      charges: {
        $map: {
          input: "$charges",
          in: {
            k: "$$this.k",
            v: {
              "$trim": {
                "input": {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: {
                      $map: {
                        input: /* Your array of index(s) */,
                        as: "i",
                        in: {
                          $arrayElemAt: [
                            "$$this.v",
                            "$$i"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: {
                      $concat: [
                        "$$value",
                        ",",
                        "$$this"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                "chars": ","
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      charges: {
        $arrayToObject: "$charges"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P94QpE8VEEd)